# How to initiate a class object out of a Dictionary with Lambda/LINQ, parsed by Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ffmpeg

since yesterday I tried to implement ffmpeg via Xabe-Wrapper in my C#-Project. 
I used FFMpeg => FFProbe to get Format and Stream data as a json-string from some movies. This is the json I got for the Streams.

```json
"{
  "streams": [
    {"codec_name": "mpeg4", "codec_type": "video"},
    {"codec_name": "mp3"  , "codec_type": "audio"}
  ]
}"
```

Follow thing the Newtonsoft [Wiki](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm), I deserialized it as a DataSet. I started playing around and found a way to do this in a "oneliner".

`Streams = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(StreamProbeJSON, 
     JSerializerSettings)).Tables["streams"].AsEnumerable().Select(value => new 
     FormatAVInfo.SInfo(value.Field<string>("codec_type"), value.Field<string> 
     ("codec_name")));`

For Format, I get this Json

```
{
    "format": {
        "format_name": "avi",
        "probe_score": 100
    }
}
```

Follow thing the Newtonsoft [Wiki](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm), I deserialized this one as a Dictionary, but I am not ably to do this in a oneliner again. Its not a big problem, but I would like to now how I can achieve this?

I tried this

```
Format = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, 
    Dictionary<string, string>>>(FormatProbeJSON, JSerializerSettings)) 
    ["format"].Select(value => new FormatAVInfo.FInfo(value["format_name"], 
    value["probe_score"]));
```

But, sure, Iam getting a KeyValuePair and not able to use a indexer for this. I also tried with JObject, with the same result. Sure, I could just make another Field

```
Dictionary<string,string> Temp = 
    (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, 
    Dictionary<string, string>>>(FormatProbeJSON, JSerializerSettings)) 
    ["format"]
```

And instanciate afterwards, but Iam curious if there is a way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you not deserializing it to a real model instead of dictionaries? Then it's just `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json)` which is a nice and short line.

Comment: Iam kind of autistic and dont like field names i can't rename. I dont know if there is something like DataContracts for this.

Comment: You can use [JsonPropertyAttribute] to rename the fields. e.g. `[JsonProperty("format_name")] public string ThisIsTheFormatName { get; set; }` and JsonConvert will map it.

Comment: Thank you, that workend. Now I'am happy. Only problem now is, that I really have now clue how to make this serialize to an Dictionary<string, foo>. I have to use the JsonArrayAttribute, right? But thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deserialize this type of data into a model, not a `Dictionary`, as it seems to have a fixed structure - not a dynamic one.

For example, let's call the model "MyMovieData".

```
public class MyMovieData
{
    [JsonProperty("streams"]
    public MovieStream[] Streams { get; set; }
}

public class MovieStream[]
{
    [JsonProperty("codec_name")]
    public string CodecName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("codec_type")]
    public string CodecType { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize it in a very simple way:

```
MyMovieData bigBuckBunnyData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyMovieData>(json);

MovieStream[] bigBuckBunnyStreams = bigBuckBunnyData.Streams;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you this works. I just hoped to have it in a List with "Video1" => { Type, etc} than a array. But this is absolutely fine

Comment: Then you can do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyMovieData[]>(json)` if you have an array of the data. Of `<List<MyMovieData>>(json)` if you prefer `List<>`.